# How to render a button inside screenOptions on Stack.Navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, drawer, react-navigation-stack

I'm still beginner in React Native and I'm trying to follow a tutorial from youtube to make a Drawer Menu.

I'm in a part of the tutorial, where I need to insert a button inside the `screenOptions` of my `Stack.Navigator`.

```js
const Screens = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTransparent: false,
        headerTitle: null,
        headerLeft: () => {
          <Button title="Menu" />;
        },
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Contact" component={Contact} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

My code is in accordance with the tutorial, but the problem is that in my code the button does not appear so that I can open `Drawer`.

Can you help me and tell me how do I render this button on my screen?

Here's my code I put in [snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/xmWtbwv8M), and here's the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iD8N6cxyffw) I'm trying follow, the button is inserted in the minute 14:40s.

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine but you are not returning the button here,

Follow this code:

```
 <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTransparent: false,
        headerTitle: null,
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Button title="Menu" />
        ),
      }}>
     //rest of the code
 </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you so much Gayatri, I feel stupid for such a silly mistake, thank you so much!!